# What is a real-world polymorphism example?

Tags: polymorphism

I read and searched about polymorphism but all I got was a theoretical definition.  What is a real-world example of the concept?

Comment: `interface control; class button inherits control; class textbox inherits control`?

Comment: I meant polymorphism that we use in writing code.

Comment: I fail to see the distinction.  Use it any time you have a list of objects, and each object has some sort of "type" and you want to do a different thing depending on their "type".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of a car, you know how to drive a car, but a gas powered car operates differntly then an electric car.  On both car you know how to make it accelerate, but on a gas based car when you hit the gas peddel you the car burn gas, but on an electric car it does not do the same thing, even though you are doing the exact same action (aka sending the same message).  So with polymorphism, you know how to send a message, but you don't care how the engin of the object does it.